# Python Stock Script Update Price every 10 seconds

Tags: python

I wrote up a python script to grab stock price and display on my LED matrix.  The issue is its very slow.
It takes about a minute to fire up and display on LED and then between scrolls its about 46-53 seconds.  How can I make this script faster?  Note: I am using this on a pizero so I get that it may be part to blame.

```
  
from samplebase import SampleBase
from rgbmatrix import graphics
import time
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs


class RunText(SampleBase):

    def run(self):
      while True:
        res = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/gme')
        soup = bs(res.content, 'lxml')
        price = soup.select_one('.intraday__price .value').text

        res1 = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/etsy')
        soup1 = bs(res1.content, 'lxml')
        price1 = soup1.select_one('.intraday__price .value').text

        res2 = requests.get('https://www.marketwatch.com/investing/stock/aapl')
        soup2 = bs(res2.content, 'lxml')
        price2 = soup2.select_one('.intraday__price .value').text

        offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.CreateFrameCanvas()
        font = graphics.Font()
        font.LoadFont("../../../fonts/6x10.bdf")
        textColor = graphics.Color(255, 255, 0)
        stock2 = graphics.Color(139, 0, 0)
        stock3 = graphics.Color(64, 0, 255)
        pos = offscreen_canvas.width
        my_text =  " GME: " + price
        my_text1 = "ETSY: " + price1
        my_text2 = "AAPL: " + price2

        while True:
            offscreen_canvas.Clear()
            len = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, pos, 10, textColor, my_text)
            len2 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, pos, 18, stock2, my_text1)
            len3 = graphics.DrawText(offscreen_canvas, font, pos, 26, stock3, my_text2)
            pos -= 1
            if (pos + len3 < 0):
                pos = offscreen_canvas.width
                break
            time.sleep(0.02)
            offscreen_canvas = self.matrix.SwapOnVSync(offscreen_canvas)

#Main function
if __name__ == "__main__":
    run_text = RunText()
    time.sleep(0.08)
    if (not run_text.process()):
        run_text.print_help()
```

Comment: which part is taking the most time? break it up into sections, do something like `start = time.time() .... code ... end = time.time() print('section time %s' % end-start)`

Comment: also, why do you have the `time.sleep(0.02)` in your loop?

Comment: @Macattack thats the scroll speed

Comment: So the issue is in my first while true statement.  That is where all the time is being held up ```1615243830.53
1615243881.22```

Comment: Have you sprinkled time hacks throughout this (`print("at A,",time.time())`) so you can see what takes the time?  I doubt the drawing it taking time.  It's not impossible that marketwatch is throttling your activity.

Comment: Easier to read output
```Start: 17:57:40
End: 17:58:29
```

Comment: @TimRoberts I thought thta at first as well but I also tried with yahoo finance with same results.

Comment: You need to print a time stamp after every major section, like every 3 lines of code.